Does anyone know why my Flutter appbar icons are appearing as circles?

I'm developing a flutter app and every time I add an appbar, the icons(leading and actions) appear as circles filled with my apps primary color. I'm not sure why this happens.
Here is my code for the appbar:
Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.budgetName),automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        actions: \[IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon:Icon(EvaIcons.edit2))\],),
         backgroundColor: kDarkScaffold,)


have tried change color of icons in iconbutton? icons might be in primary color so that it apears as in circles.

You may have a background/fill color set for icons in either your Theme.iconButtonTheme or Theme.appBarTheme.actionsIconTheme. You could test by wrapping your widget in a Theme widget where you pass in Theme.of(context).copyWith(appBarTheme..) etc.

@rhpekarek That was it. When defining custom themes I had modified icon colors. Thank you
